# How do I set the Title of an Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

My question comes in two parts:

- Where does the Title field in the Listing Details display (Developer Console)?
- How does one set the title that appears under the icon of the app?

I do not need very detailed answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  I'll have something like

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:debuggable="false">
   ...
</appliation>
```

Then find the `app_name` string in your string resources file:

```
<string name="app_name">My application</string>
```

That's your application name.  It will be displayed in the title bar and under the icon on the device.

When you upload an app to the market (sorry, google-play), you can enter a 30-char title of your app.  Normally, you would enter the same title as you have in your app, however it can be different.  Whatever you put into that field will be displayed as the title of the app when users search for or view details of your app in the Market (sorry, google play).

As a test, I just changed the name of one of my apps in the dev console and then searched for that app in the market.  The new name was displayed when I opened the app details.  However when I install that app, its name is what I have included in the manifest.  (I changed the name back now.)

Comment: That answers the second part of my question, but not the first: Where does the Title field in the Listing Details display (from Developer Console)?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I follow your question. The value of `android:label` is used both in the application itself (title bar and icon) and in the developer console.

Comment: Hmm... The field is editable before I upload the .apk file and has a limit of 30 characters. It's on the Product Details tab, in the section labeled "Listing details".

Comment: Yes, you're right, I must have forgotten about that part (it's been a while since I submitted my last app).  This title is displayed in the Android Market when somebody is searching for and looking at the details of your apps.  I'm updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: I find the 30 Character limit to be excessively constrained. One of my company's media properties, The Atlanta-Journal Constitution, is 32 characters. That does not even include the words we'd like to add to the titles to distinguish the separate apps we will publish for each property.